# How to run Thunderbird in background and pop up notifications for new e-mails?

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, background-process

Recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 and configured Thunderbird email client. 
But seems like the email client is not working in background (like Rhythmbox).

Need to keep running that like other foreground application to get mail notifications.

Is there any solution, any add-on or plug-ins?

Answer (score 8):

Found the solution with **[FireTray](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/firetray/)** is an extension for Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the [MinimizeToTray revived (MinTrayR)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-revived/) extension, because it **only uses the default Ubuntu Messaging Menu**, rather than adding a new icon in the tray to Thunderbird, as [FireTray](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/firetray/) does. Thus, you need not fill the tray with icons.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to your question is using Popper.

To install it from its PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ralf.hersel/rhersel-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install popper
```

This will check for email in the background and notify you:
[image]